# A value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

Tags: c++, string, struct, char

I've seen a couple threads dealing with similar errors, but they were all dealing with different variations of the problem from the one I have encountered (code for: "I'm too green to make sense of them").

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    struct StudentRecord
    {
        char name[20];
        int id;
        float gpa;
    };

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Enter your name:" << endl;
        char nameInput[20];
        cin >> nameInput;

        cout << "Enter your student ID:" << endl;
        int idInput;
        cin >> idInput;

        cout << "Enter your GPA:" << endl;
        float gpaInput;
        cin >> gpaInput;

        StudentRecord TESCStudent =
        { { nameInput }, idInput, gpaInput }; // TROUBLE STARTS HERE

    cout << "Name: " << TESCStudent.name << "\nID: " << TESCStudent.id << "\nGPA: "
        << TESCStudent.gpa << endl;
}
```

The StudentRecord TESCStudent = {...} initializer gives the following errors:
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char [20]' to 'char' 
IntelliSense:  a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

I realize that an string would solve a lot of problems, but the project asked that we get the name as a 20 character array.

This is my first time using a struct, so I may be doing something horrendous without meaning to, please go easy on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> `StudentRecord TESCStudent = { { nameInput }, idInput, gpaInput };`

Basically: you can't do that.  C-style arrays have unintuitive syntax and semantics; and there is no way to initialize the elements of a C-style array using another C-style array other than by listing each element individually.

My advice would be to not use them at all.  If you used `std::string` instead of the name array then you could simply write `StudentRecord TESCStudent = { nameInput , idInput, gpaInput };`.  This would also fix the problem that your code causes a buffer overflow if the person types in a name of length 20 characters or more.

If you are forced to stick with the char array due to course requirements then I'd suggest avoiding the issue by reading directly into the array, and adding overflow protection and error checking, for example:

```
StudentRecord TESCStudent = {};

 cout << "Enter your name:" << endl;
 cin >> setw(sizeof(TESCStudent.name)) >> TESCStudent.name;

 cout << "Enter your student ID:" << endl;
 cin >> TESCStudent.id;

 cout << "Enter your GPA:" << endl;
 cin >> TESCStudent.gpa;

 if ( !cin )
 {
     cout << "Invalid input, sorry.\n";
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on how your code limits the input to 20 characters. Could you elaborate on that? Also, I was forced to use the array (which sucked) but I'm interested in the way you read directly to the array, I will try that in the future!

Comment: @KeeperofSecrets `setw` sets the maximum size for the next read (incl null termination if it's a char array)

Comment: Cool. This is a great solution, much cleaner and more elegant than the for loop I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

@yinch rightly pointed out that I was treating `idInput` as a value instead of an array. Writing it as:

`StudentRecord TESCStudent = { { *nameInput }, idInput, gpaInput };`

removes the error, but only adds the first value from `nameInput[20]` to `TESCStudent.name[20]`. I decided to add the values to TESCStudent like this:

```
    StudentRecord TESCStudent; // create a variable from StudentRecord

    cout << "Enter your name:" << endl; // prompt for name
    char nameInput[20];
    cin >> nameInput;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) // assign each element of nameInput
                                     // to TESCStudent.name explicitly
    {
        TESCStudent.name[ i ] = nameInput[ i ];
    }

    cout << "\nEnter your student ID:" << endl; // prompt for ID
    int idInput;
    cin >> idInput;
    TESCStudent.id = idInput; // assign idInput to TESCStudent.id

    cout << "\nEnter your GPA:" << endl; // prompt for GPA
    float gpaInput;
    cin >> gpaInput;
    TESCStudent.gpa = gpaInput; // assign gpaInput to TESCStudent.gpa
```

The for loop solves the problem by assigning each array value to TESCStudent.name explicitly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Changing the problem line to:

```
    StudentRecord TESCStudent =
        { { *nameInput }, idInput, gpaInput };
```

fixes the problem.

The thing to remember about strings is that they are, themselves, arrays.
So In your example, "nameInput" by itself doesn't hold a char value, it actually holds a pointer to the first char value.

Distinguishing between variables (which hold value) and pointers (which are address pointers pointing to locations that hold the value) is a crucial part of the difference between strings and other literal values (like int and float)

By pre-fixing the nameInput (pointer) with an asterisk indicates that you want the value that the pointing at.

Comment: That answers the big question. I knew that there was something wrong with the way I was using the char array, but couldn't figure out how to fix it. Incidentally, `*nameInput` only adds the first element in the array to the `name` array. I've reworked the name initialization with a for loop.

Comment: `*nameInput` means the first character of the array only